# Portlet is emty when I deploy it

Tags: jsp, servlets, liferay

I'm using Liferay and my portlet class is as follow:

```
public class HospitalPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
private static Log _log = LogFactory.getLog(HospitalPortlet.class);
public void doLogin(ActionRequest actionRequest, 
        ActionResponse actionResponse)
            throws IOException, PortletException{
    actionRequest.setAttribute("test", "this is a test");
}
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse)
            throws IOException, PortletException{
    renderRequest.setAttribute("test", "this is a test");
    include("view.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
public void include(String path,
        RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
            throws IOException, PortletException{
    PortletRequestDispatcher portletRequestDispatcher =
            getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path);
    if (portletRequestDispatcher == null){
        _log.error(path + " is not a valid include");
    }
    else{
        portletRequestDispatcher.include(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
}

}
```

and my viw.jsp is as follow:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>Hospital</b> portlet.

<%
    String testVar = (String)renderRequest.getAttribute("test");    
%>

<br />

<p><%= testVar %></p>
```

I depoly this portlet and place it on the page, but it is empty and there is no error message in liferay log file. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove include method

`public void include(String path,
        RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)`

don't remove `include("view.jsp", renderRequest, renderResponse)`;

in `doView()`

and deploy your code

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the include method and include line in doView Method. I am assuming you just have one page called view.jsp. Also double check portlet.xml of the portlet and see if portlet-class is not pointing to MVCPortlet but to HospitalPortlet class.

Answer (score 0):

In spring mvc portlet I face this issue and the mistake that I made is I forgot to replace line portlet.xml file is

```
com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet
```

I have to replace with

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet
```

Once I replace this error gone.